# Assist to understand linux _start

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, program-entry-point

```
000003b0 <_start>:
 3b0:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 3b2:   5e                      pop    %esi
 3b3:   89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx
 3b5:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 3b8:   50                      push   %eax
 3b9:   54                      push   %esp
 3ba:   52                      push   %edx
 3bb:   e8 22 00 00 00          call   3e2 <_start+0x32>
 3c0:   81 c3 1c 1c 00 00       add    $0x1c1c,%ebx
 3c6:   8d 83 94 e5 ff ff       lea    -0x1a6c(%ebx),%eax
 3cc:   50                      push   %eax
 3cd:   8d 83 34 e5 ff ff       lea    -0x1acc(%ebx),%eax
 3d3:   50                      push   %eax
 3d4:   51                      push   %ecx
 3d5:   56                      push   %esi
 3d6:   ff b3 1c 00 00 00       pushl  0x1c(%ebx)
 3dc:   e8 af ff ff ff          call   390 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 3e1:   f4                      hlt    
 3e2:   8b 1c 24                mov    (%esp),%ebx
 3e5:   c3                      ret    
 3e6:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 3e8:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 3ea:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 3ec:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 3ee:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Hey, guys, plz do me a favour to understand this code snippet after addr 3b8. I can guess what it is doing but not really specific.

BTW, if you guys have any clue to teach me how to figure out the implementation of Linux calling system ON SPECIFIC CODE, plz let me know. Thx.

After check the ABI doc, still not quite understand why it jumps to 3e2, cuz it seems that they did nothing but jump back.

Comment: Based on my current understanding, at the beginning of _start section, the stack is not empty at all, so as some general purpose registers, I realized there might be some caller above _start, I am trying to get some clues from github.com/torvalds/linux/-/blob/arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S

Comment: Have a look at the i386 System V ABI doc.  It specifies the user-space stack layout on entry to `_start`.  e.g. ESP points at `argc`, and `argv[]` is above that (the array contents, not a pointer).  Also note that this is a PIE executable so it thunks the return address into EBX for PC-relative addressing.

Comment: you are GREAT! Thx.

Comment: re: your edit: read the last paragraph of my answer.  x86-64 code would just use RIP-relative addressing but 32-bit x86 doesn't have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the i386 System V ABI doc.  (https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).  It also documents the function-calling convention in complete detail.  (It gets intense, sometimes it's easier to just look at how GCC `-O2` compiles arg-passing or return of a struct by value.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/)

It specifies the user-space stack layout on entry to `_start`.  e.g. ESP points at `argc`, and `argv[]` is above that (the array contents, not a pointer).  `envp[]` above that.  Also note that in a dynamically-linked executable, `_start` is jumped to from the dynamic linker's own startup code.  That's where the atexit pointer comes from.

Also note that this is a PIE executable so it thunks the return address into EBX for PC-relative addressing with the `call 3e2`.